# How to find a subgroup between two groups

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Consider symmetric group $S_{11}$. I considered the group $H$ generated by permutations
$a=(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,1)$ and $b=(11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)$. I want to find a group $K$ strictly
larger than $H$ and smaller than $S_{11}$. So I want to get $H \subsetneq K \subsetneq S_{11}$.
I took some random permutation $c$ and considered the group generated by $(a,b,c)$. But it becomes $S_{11}$. Any idea how to tackle this?

Sorry, probably I am missing. But my Sage code is giving as follows:

```
n=11
G=SymmetricGroup(n)
a=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,1]
b=[11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

Ha=G.subgroup([a])
print Ha, len(Ha)

Hb=G.subgroup([b])
print Hb, len(Hb)

Hab=G.subgroup([a,b])
print Hab, len(Hab)


Subgroup of (Symmetric group of order 11! as a permutation group) generated by [(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)] 11
Subgroup of (Symmetric group of order 11! as a permutation group) generated by [(1,11)(2,10)(3,9)(4,8)(5,7)] 2
Subgroup of (Symmetric group of order 11! as a permutation group) generated by [(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11), (1,11)(2,10)(3,9)(4,8)(5,7)] 22
```

Comment: You have not tried very hard, because if you choose $c$ to be an even permutation, then $\langle a,b,c \rangle \le A_{11}$.

Comment: The element $b$ that you input to Sage is not $(11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)$, but $(1,11)(2,10)(3,9)(4,8)(5,7)$. Since the $b$ that you wrote in your question is equal to $a^{-1}$, I would guess that that was a mistake, and that the correct $b$ is the one you input to Sage. That means that Andrea Mori's answer no longer applies, and my rather easy answer $A_{11}$ is also wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First of all $b=a^{-1}=a^{10}$ so $H$ is simply the subgroup of order $11$ generated by $a$.

There are many ways to produce a group $K$ as you wish. For instance you may consider the permutation
$$
s=(2\ 11)(3\ 10)(4\ 9)(5\ 8)(6\ 7).
$$
Then the subgroup $K$ generated by $a$ and $s$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_{11}$ of the isometries of the regular $11$-gon.

That is rather obvious since if you number the vertices in order from $1$ to $11$, $a$ is the basic rotation and $s$ is the reflexion around the axis through vertex $1$ and the center.

Comment: A more mundane example is $A_{11}$. A more interesting example is $\langle (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11), (1, 2, 10, 6, 3, 5, 9, 7, 4, 8, 11) \rangle \cong {\rm PSL}(2,11)$.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the intended permutation $b$ in your question is not $(11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)$, which is just equal to $a^{-1}$, but $(1,11)(2,10)(3,9)(4,8)(5,7)$.

If that is the case, then $|\langle a,b \rangle| = 22$, and the subgroup $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ with $c = (2, 4, 10, 6, 5)(3, 7, 8, 11, 9)$ has order $110$. (This the normalizer of $\langle a \rangle$ in $S_{11}$, and it is (I think) the unique correct answer.)